# SQL join on two table and replace and return columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I am working on some SQL query with joins and I want to get the corresponding value from another table which matches with original table columns values.

For example, I have two different tables named `Product` and `Category` and they are as follows:

**Products:**

```
| id | name    | category1                 | category2    | category3   |
| -- | ------- | ------------------------- |--------------------------- |
| 1  | T-shirt | Cloths&Accessories~:/ID1  | Cloths~:/ID2 | Shirts~:/ID3|
|----|---------|---------------------------|------------- |-------------|
| 2  | T-shirt | Cloths&Accessories~:/ID1  | Cloths~:/ID2 | Shirts~:/ID3|
|----|---------|---------------------------|------------- |-------------|
| 3  | T-shirt | Cloths&Accessories~:/ID1  | Cloths~:/ID2 | Shirts~:/ID3|
|----|---------|---------------------------|------------- |-------------|
| 4  | T-shirt | Cloths&Accessories~:/ID1  | Cloths~:/ID2 | Shirts~:/ID3|
|----|---------|---------------------------|------------- |-------------|
| 5  | T-shirt | Cloths&Accessories~:/ID1  | Cloths~:/ID2 | Shirts~:/ID3|
|----|---------|---------------------------|------------- |-------------|
```

And **Category:**

```
| id | categories           |
| -- | -------------------- |
| 1  | Cloths & Accessories |
|----|--------------------- |
| 2  | Cloths               |
|----|--------------------- |
| 3  | Shirts               |
|----|--------------------- |
```

The problem is, in table `Product` there is this `Cloths&Accessories~:/ID1` kind of Invalid strings stored under column names `category1`, `category2` and `category3` and I want to replace them with valid category names from table `Category`. If you look at the table `Category` the id of each category matches with string `Cloths&Accessories~:/ID1` having `ID1` in it.

For example:
`Cloths&Accessories~:/ID1` in this string `ID1` is related to id=1 of table `Category` which is `Cloths & Accessories`

I have to replace and return all of `category1`, `category2` and `category3` columns of table `Product` with valid `categories`.

What would be the optimal SQL join query for this?

Comment: It's not clear to me if you want a NoSQL model or a SQL model. If you want foreign keys the relational model requires them to be consistent. If this is a NoSQL model, then there shouldn't be foreign keys in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`substring_index`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to extract the ID, and then join on it:

```sql
SELECT p.id AS id,
       p.name AS name,
       c1.categories AS category1,
       c2.categories AS category2,
       c3.categories AS category3
FROM   products p
JOIN   category c1 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.category1, 'ID', -1) = c1.id
JOIN   category c2 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.category2, 'ID', -1) = c2.id
JOIN   category c3 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.category3, 'ID', -1) = c3.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Could you tell what `c1.categories, c2.categories and c3.categories` does?

Comment: @trojanatwar those are the names of the categories you wanted to query